# Get url of scripts and styles in document head

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there any way to get the URLs of external CSS & Javascripts loaded in the head of a document?

so for instance in head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/somewhere/script.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/somewhere/styles.css">
```

How would I get `/path/somewhere/script.js` and `/path/somewhere/styles.css` from DOM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `querySelector` and extract the appropriate properties:

```
const script = document.querySelector('head > script');
console.log(script.src);
const css = document.querySelector('head > link');
console.log(css.href);
```

(doesn't work in snippet due to sandboxing)

Or if you need all script/css URLs, and not just one of each, loop over them:

```
document.querySelectorAll('head > script')
  .forEach(script => console.log(script.src));
document.querySelectorAll('head > link')
  .forEach(css => console.log(css.href));
```

Comment: Will also return `ld+json` etc., possibly need to add `type` to selector

Comment: [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) will only find the first matching element. To find all matches, use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), which returns a DOM [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Comment: You can even narrow your search for external scripts which have a `src` attribute: `document.querySelectorAll('head > script[src]')`

Comment: I actually didn't know I could specify head tag in selector.  Obvious in hindsight.  Many thanks.

Comment: @Guerrilla: You could use the `head` as the root too. Makes the selector slightly more efficient. `document.head.querySelectorAll("script")`

Comment: @CrazyTrain [`document.head.getElementsByTagName('script')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) might be even more efficient, because it doesn’t have to parse the CSS selector. I’m not sure that it’s more efficient, because it returns a live [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) instead of a static [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Comment: @RoryO'Kane: Yeah, I'm not sure either. Likely a tiny difference with any of these approaches.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    let scriptTags = document.querySelectorAll('head > script');
    scriptTags.forEach(scriptTag => {
        console.log(scriptTag.getAttribute('src'));
    });

    let linkTags = document.querySelectorAll('head > link');
    linkTags.forEach(linkTag => {
        console.log(linkTag.getAttribute('href'));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use `let` unless you intend to reassign the variable - which should be avoided if possible. Also, ordinary Javascript dot notation is preferable to parsing the HTML attribute of an element.

Comment: @CertainPerformance to clarify, when you say "don't use let...", I think you're implying to use `const` instead, correct?

Comment: @jbyrd That's right. Code is *much* clearer when you know you aren't going to be reassigning a variable.